# Vue3 Typescript error on registering component inside another

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I have a Vue3 component (using TS) in which I'm trying to render another component inside it like this:

**TopBar.vue**

```
<template> <TopBarProfileDropdown /> </template>
<script lang="ts">
import TopBarProfileDropdown from 'components/layout/TopBarProfileDropdown';
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'TopBar',
  components: { TopBarProfileDropdown },
  setup() {
    return {}
  }
})
</script>
```

But I'm getting a TS compilation error:

[image]

How can I type assert an imported component and fix this?

**EDIT1** Adding imported component:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'TopBarProfileDropdown',
  setup() {
    return {}
  }
})
</script>
```

The component type is something like:

```
import TopBarProfileDropdown: ComponentPublicInstanceConstructor<...>
```

Comment: What is the type of the imported component? (You can hover over it in most editors to see type info.) Can you include the code of the imported component?

Comment: @DarrylNoakes Added requested information.

Comment: The error is probably caused by the missing file extension from the import path. Append `.vue`.